# Easy way to get original header for read.table in R

Tags: r, file-io, import

I'm importing a tab-delimited text file with `read.table`. The problem is that column header there (the 1st line) contains many special characters that got substituted with dots after import. I understand the reason but I still need to have the original header for labels, outputs, etc. How I can import the original header without much hassle with low-level input?

Comment: Would adding `header=F` to your read.table work? This would make the first observation the column labels, and R automatically gives the columns the names: V1, V2, etc. You could then process the first row to make better names for your dataset. (Or, I suppose, you could reread the header row using `read.table(file, header=F, nrow=1)`)

Comment: Will it make all the columns text instead of numbers? I have a mixture of textual and numeric fields (and I don't know in advance what is what). Currently they import properly. If I have to convert text to numbers that will be a lot of additional troubles.

Comment: Yea, I realized that after posting that, see my edit - If you have numeric data, I would go through a second pass and read just the header row. Unless someone else knows a better way :)

Comment: did you try check.names=FALSE ?

Comment: I wonder reading only header will be the same problem.

Comment: @cory, Yep, that works! Thanks a lot. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check.names=FALSE` should do it...

Answer (score 2):

`check.names=FALSE` should do the trick:

```
read.table(filename, header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry, that I accepted another answer, since it was done earlier in comments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column names after you have already imported the data set.

```
names(df) <- c("c1Name", "c2Name", ...)
```

From here you can add special characters

Comment: You misunderstood. I need to export the header from the file.